# Strictness in both arguments but not in each individually

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, haskell

I'm learning about strict functions in Haskell.
A function f is strict if f ⊥ = ⊥ 
Some functions are strict only in the first argument (for e.g. const), others are strict in the second (for e.g. map).
I'm trying to think of a function which is strict in only both arguments at the same time, so
f x ⊥ is not bottom
f ⊥ y is not bottom
but 
f ⊥ ⊥ is bottom
and I can't come up with any such function. Is this possible?

It feels like it isn't, but I'm a bit confused.
Also because of currying, we can think of the function as only taking one argument at a time and then returning a function that takes the second argument. Do we only talk about strictness in one argument at a time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a very good question! It turns out the answer is both yes and no.

A classic example of a function we'd like to write is [Plotkin's parallel or](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/LCF.pdf). We know from basic boolean logic that both `or True _` and `or _ True` are always true, regardless of the value of `_`. So we'd like to write a function `or` that takes two arguments, and `True` if either argument is `True`, returns `False` if both arguments are `False`, and only doesn't terminate if neither argument terminates. But can we?

It turns out that in the lambda calculus, it's impossible to write such a function. The lambda calculus is said to be *inherently sequential*. I've written a bit about this in the past in [Why are there two not operators in lambda calculus?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102290/why-are-there-two-not-operators-in-lambda-calculus/102308#102308), on a related example.

If you think in terms of Turing machines, it *is* possible to write a machine that performs parallel `or`. Consider a machine with two inputs: a description of a machine $M_1$ that calculates the first argument, and a description of a machine $M_2$ that calculates the second argument. The machine simulates one step of $M_1$, then one step of $M_2$, then again one step of each machine in turn, until one of the machine halts. If the first machine to halt outputs `True`, output `True` and stop, otherwise keep simulating the other machine and return its output (if it ever terminates).

This illustrates an important aspect of the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis). All definitions of things we'd sensibly want to call “this can be computer” turn out to be equivalent, as long as the intuition of computability is only about taking inputs and returning a result. If we throw other things into the mix, such as looking at computations in progress and giving it a meaning other than the final output, then models of computation are not equivalent. In particular, there isn't an equivalent of the Church-Turing thesis for concurrent computation: different models often have subtle differences in terms of expressivity.